# Visual Studio 2008 Database Edition - what is it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2008-db

What is Visual Studio 2008 Database Edition -- is it different from Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition?

Answer (score 3):

Great explanation [here](http://www.microsoft.com/australia/visualstudio/products/teamSystem/default.mspx):

> Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition provides advanced tools for database change management and testing and offers functionality to enable database developers and administrators to be more productive and increase application quality in the database tier.
>
> Highlights:
>
> - Rename Refactoring support for database objects
> - Team Foundation Server Workgroup Edition: Team Suite Editions include an MSDN Premium Subscription, giving you Team Foundation Server Workgroup Edition. It provides the full functionality of Team Foundation Server for up to five users, including a team portal, version control, work-item tracking, build management, process guidance and business intelligence in one unified server. For more than five users, select the the full edition of Team Foundation Server.
> - Schema Compare to keep two schema versions synchronized
> - Data Compare to keep the data in two databases synchronized
> - Offline database projects for change isolation
> - Extensible unit test functionality
> - Data generator to define sets of repeatable test data
> - New designer enables users to create T-SQL with the same fidelity as managed code
> - Bonus! Development Edition is included – get both sets of functionality for the price of one!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is different from Professional Edition. Database Edition is targeted at database admins/devs/etc - people whose work is primarily done in DBs.

http://peterkellner.net/2009/01/17/visual-studio-database-edition-review-sqlserver2008/
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/teamsystem/default.mspx